# Requested user profile present at two urls

Tags: django

For logged-in user the profile url is

```
path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),
```

For profile views the url is

```
re_path(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',UserProfileView,name='my_profile'),
```

But when we try to access the logged-in user by '/profile/user_pk' then it was conflicting one profile present at two urls

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    args={'user':request.user}
    return render(request,'account/profile.html',args)

def UserProfileView(request,pk):
    if pk==request.user.pk:
        raise(Http404)
    else:
        user = get_object_or_404(User,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'account/profile.html',{'user':user})
```

something like if requested pk is same as profile pk then it raises Http else show other profile but now working still showing all profile as it was showing.

Comment: What do you mean by `conflicting one profile present at two urls`?

Comment: one profile of user who are logged-in and their profile also seen from this url 'profile/1' if 1 is pk of that logged-in user

Comment: I think it's fine to have logged in user use the same url as others i.e. `profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/` I would in fact avoid creating different 'profile/' url for logged in user.

Comment: Secondly, it does not seem correct to return 404 for your custom logic. You can use the second view for all the profiles including the logged in user and based on login session, enable/disable the features on profile page.

Comment: okk i will try to figure out else go with your method

Comment: ok ok thanks a lot now i think i am on right track